# Trying to get enemy to deal damage every set seconds (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am creating a 3D Shooter and I am trying to make an enemy deal damage to the player every set seconds. I have made the enemy deal damage with a raycast but it deals the damage way too fast.

I thought using yield return new WaitForSeconds(2) would take 1 damage away from the player every 2 seconds but it deals damage to the player a lot faster.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Transform player;
    public float enemySpeed;
    public int moveTrigger = 1;
    public int isAttacking;

    public float distanceFromPlayer;

    void Update()
    {
        distanceFromPlayer = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, player.transform.position);

        if (distanceFromPlayer <= 10 && moveTrigger == 1)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target);
            StartCoroutine(EnemyDamage());
        }
        if (distanceFromPlayer <10 && moveTrigger == 1 && distanceFromPlayer >3)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * enemySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyDamage()
    {
        RaycastHit PlayerHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(target.transform.position, target.transform.forward, out PlayerHit))
        {
            Debug.Log(PlayerHit.transform.name);
            Target target = PlayerHit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                GlobalHealth.playerHealth -= 1;
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The gamer/game designer speak is: "I want to apply a 'Damage over Time' (DoT) Effect to the player." | Note that you do not usually measure in seconds, but in game ticks. You are looking for a timer that actually counts on game ticks, not real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, you are starting a new coroutine each frame. You should do all your waiting and looping inside your coroutine, as execution exits *and re-enters* your coroutine from the yeild statment. This is how you would write this to work

```
// in update
if (distanceFromPlayer <= 10 && moveTrigger == 1){
        transform.LookAt(target);
        if(!isAttacking)
            StartCoroutine(EnemyDamage());
}
```

---

```
IEnumerator EnemyDamage()
{
    isAttacking = true;
    while(distanceFromPlayer <= 10){ // in range
        RaycastHit PlayerHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(target.transform.position, target.transform.forward, out PlayerHit)){
            Target target = PlayerHit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null){
                GlobalHealth.playerHealth -= 1;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);      
            }
        }
    }
    isAttacking = false; // out of range
    yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a coroutine in every update loop so every frame your damage coroutine gets called and applies your 1 damage after 2 seconds. 
If you want a damage over time effect the suggestion of using an game tick timer is correct, but if you want your enemy to only be able to attack every x seconds you need to implement some kind of cooldown on your damage function. For example add up Time.deltaTime until the time you want has past, and only then the enemy is able to deal damage again. You can do that with a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FixedUpdate` → set a local variable `bool alreadyShoot = false`.

- In your `EnemyDamage()` add a `if(!alreadyShoot)` before damages application and set `alreadyShoot` to `true` after damages application.
- In `FixedUpdate` you can set `alreadyShoot` to `false`.

You can choose an other solution to set `alreadyShoot` to `false` instead of `FixedUpdate` (for example a coroutine that trigger each seconds, ...)

Answer (score 0):

in update loop, check when two seconds have passed when the player is in range

```
float timeInRange = 0.0f;
bool inRange = false;

if (distanceFromPlayer <= 10 && moveTrigger == 1)
{
    inRange = true;
} 
else 
{
    inRange = false;
    timeInRange = 0;
}

if (inRange) 
{
    timeInRange += Time.DeltaTime;
}

if (timeInRange > 2.0f) 
{
    GlobalHealth.playerHealth -= 1;
    timeInRange = 0.0f;
}
```